# Precedence of Django url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I have been working with an e-commerce platform developing by django rest framework. Day by day the number of urls is increasing and there are many API endpoints (urls) which design structure is similar.

Such as:

`/api/user/<str:user_uniq_id>/`

`/api/user/sigin/`

`/api/user/registration/`

`/api/user/invitation/edit/`

`/api/user/invitation/<str:uniq_id>/`

Sometimes when I hit any url, another url gets fired. suppose I hit `/api/user/<str:user_uniq_id>` but `/api/user/signin/` gets called.

**How can I resolve this issue ?**

**Is there any ordering precedence of django urls ?**

Comment: Well your `<str:user_uniq_id>` will capture all other patterns like `signin`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**: make **non-overlapping** patterns.

The problem is that your patterns overlap. Indeed, if the url is `/api/user/signin/`, and  the `/api/user/<str:user_uniq_id>/` is the first pattern in your list of URLs, it will match that pattern. Indeed, since the `<str:user_uniq_id>` can simply be unified with `signin`. The fact that there is another url later in the list that matches as well, is not relevant.

Therefore you should design *non-overlapping* patterns. So that means that no url that can be generated by one pattern, can be generated by another pattern.

For example you can design your urls as:

```
/api/user/details/<str:user_uniq_id>/
/api/user/signin/
/api/user/registration/
/api/user/invitation/edit/
/api/user/invitation/details/<str:uniq_id>/
```

By thus using `/details`, there is no way that a URL `/api/user/sigin` can match the first pattern, since it needs to contain `/api/user/details` as prefix.

Altnatively, you can put the `/api/user/signin` path first in the list of paths. But that does not look like a good idea to me. If later a user has as `uniq_id` simply `'signin'` (yes that may look rare, but eventually it can happen), then that user can not see his/her "details" page.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply place the all the predefined urls first as mentioned below,that way if the url matches with them then it will hit it,otherwise it will move to the other urls.

```
/api/user/sigin/

/api/user/registration/

/api/user/<str:user_uniq_id>/

/api/user/invitation/edit/

/api/user/invitation/<str:uniq_id>/
```