# How to make two urls to the same app in Django?

Tags: python, django, url

It's my main **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('account.urls')),
]
```

And it's my **urls.py** of 'product' app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.getProductPage),
    path('category/<slug:slug>/', views.getCategoryProducts),
]
```

I would like to have such links:

`localhost/category/smartphones` - shows all smartphones

`localhost/xiaomi-redmi-note-7` - shows a page of xiaomi redmi note 7 smartphone

The problem is that '' directs to 'account' app and i'll not able to create localhost/slug:slug link

Comment: have you included your product app `urls.py` in the main `urls.py` file?

Comment: No' i haven't done it

Comment: i understand, but my question is how to create these links if i include product app urls.py

Comment: django always starts matching urls from root urls file unless the urls file is mentioned there it won't find any.

Comment: May be you don't understand me. If i add link to main urls.py like
path('', include('product.urls')), it'll now work(but i need that for the second link) cuz '' link is for account app

Comment: can your urls start like this? `localhost/product/category/smartphones` and `localhost/product/xiaomi-redmi-note-7`

Comment: No, it's a reason why i'd like to have links above

Comment: cuz i know how to implement your links

Answer (score 0):

Try to include your product urls above the account urls. But I think sometimes you may get overlapping url. Please read this [Precedence of Django url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59643424/precedence-of-django-url). Hope my answer help you.